# Dimension and basis of a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have the following $\mathbb{C}$-algebra;

$\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3,xy,y^2)$

and I am trying to determine its dimension, as well as the basis of the algebra as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space.

Unfortunately I'm having a little trouble getting started, so any hints or indication of how this would be done would be appreciated

Comment: What *dimensions* are you talking about?

Comment: Apologies for the typo, should read *dimension, as in the cardinality of the basis of the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. Have edited the typo in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: prove that any polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is congruent, modulo $(x^3,xy,y^2)$, to a polynomial of the form
$$
a+bx+cx^2+dy
$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I have proved this, and concluded that every element in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3,xy,y^2)$ is of this form, and so the vector space has dimension 4 with basis $\{1,[x],[x^2],[y]\}$.

Comment: @Munkres Yes, that's it!